# The second coefficient of the Conway polynomial from Knot Floer homology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, heegaard-floer-homology

Let $\nabla_K(z)$ be the Conway polynomial and $\Delta_K(t)$ be the Alexander polynomial normalized by $\Delta_K(t)=\Delta_K(t^{-1})$ and $\Delta_K(1)=1$,
These invariants are equivalent and they are related by $\Delta_K(t)=\nabla_K(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})$.

Let $a_2(K)$ be the coefficient of $z^{2}$ of the Conway polynomial $\nabla_K(z)$ which is known as the simplest finite type invariant of degree two. Since the knot Floer homology is a categorification of the Alexander polynomial and $a_2(K)=\frac{1}{2}\Delta''_K(1)$, one can read $a_2(K)$ from the knot Floer chain complex.

**Question:**
Is there a good formula of $a_2(K)$ in terms of the knot Floer theory?

**Why I expect there is a good formula:**

- $a_2(K)$ is a fundamental knot invariant having many applications.
  Here is a simple example where the knot Floer homology gives a non-trivial information. If $K$ is an L-space knot, then its Alexander polynomial
  $\Delta_K(t)$ is of the form
  $\Delta_K(t)=(-1)^{k} + \sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}(t^{n_j}+ t^{-n_j})$
  for some $0<n_1<n_2 < \cdots < n_k=g(K)$.
  By a direct computation, this implies that
  $a_2(K) > 0$, so an L-space knot has positive $a_2(K)$. Thus it seems that the knot floer homology also provides various properties of $a_2(K)$, hence it is natural to expect good interpretations.
- Let $\lambda$ be the Casson(-Walker) invariant (to make argument simple, I restrict the integral homology spheres). The surgery formula of Casson invariant says that $\lambda(S^{3}(1/q)) = q a_2(K)$ for $1/q$-surgery on a knot $K$ in $S^{3}$. On the other hand, the Casson-Walker invariant is closely related to the correction terms $d(Y)$ and $HF_{red}(Y)$ as $\lambda(Y) = \chi(HF_{red}(Y))-\frac{1}{2}d(Y)$. Thus the surgery formula of the corection terms and Heegaard Floer homology seems to give a formula of $a_2(K)$ (though the formula obtained in this way seems to be complicated).

Comment: Hi there Tetsuya.  Can you define what "good" means?

Comment: I mean, a way to compute (or deduce) a_2(K) from knot Floer chain complex, without computing whole Alexander polynomial (and its derivatives). For example, I am happy if there is a direct explanation of aforementioned a_2(K)>0 for an L-space knot K. Of course, I understand the meaning of `good' depends on the person...